# Не отображается favicon в google

Tags: html, favicon

Favicon добавил как руками, так и в самом движке WP.
Иконка отображается в браузере, в яндексе и так далее, но вот в мобильной версии google - какая-то заглушка. Сегодня гугл добавил иконки и в десктоп версии, там у сайта тоже заглушка

Очень прошу помощи https://right-store.ru/

---

Мужчины, есть ещё идеи?

Переиндексирование запускаю руками:
Последнее сканирование
13 нояб. 2019 г., 12:34:01

Робот, выполнивший сканирование
Робот Googlebot для смартфонов

Сканирование разрешено?
Да

Получение страницы
Успешно

Comment: На будущее: лучше приводить не ссылку на сайт, а код. Хотя в этот конкретный раз проблема оказалась не в коде, а правах доступа. [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/213987)

Comment: Проблема не исправилась, увы и ах

Comment: То, что гугл проиндексировал - ещё не значит, что гугл сразу обновит у себя информацию и начнёт показывать. Ждите, иногда это занимает месяц.

Answer (score 1):

favicon был недоступен боту по прямой ссылке, проблема с правами доступа.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

От вас очень мало информации для точного ответа.

1. Дайте Google больше времени
2. Ваш код не оптимизирован под браузеры и устройства: IE8-10, iOS, OSX, под некоторые Desktop устройства.

Answer (score 0):

Ну он отображется нормально, если идет речь о галочке оранжевой. Обычно если не появляется, нужно почистить кеш браузера и кеш WP, и тогда все появится